# How can I move windows in Windows with keyboard?

Tags: windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, plugins

I recently started using Linux and was floored by the ease with which windows can be moved and resized with simple keyboard combinations using Compiz. If I want to move a terminal to top-right of the screen a simple CTRL+ALT+Numpad9 does the trick for me, and it resizes the window at the same time. I'm sure you guys know what I'm talking about.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in windows.

Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to clarify that I am looking to do this on Windows Vista ... man, this makes me want to upgrade even more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [WinSplit Revolution](http://www.winsplit-revolution.com/), it has what you need and is customizable.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you're on an older version of Windows, the old standby is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get the system menu, <kbd>M</kbd> and then the arrow keys to move the window around.  If you're maximized, first you need to hit <kbd>R</kbd> on the system menu, which will un-maximize you.  Not as elegant, but it works in a pinch.

Comment: It should be Alt+Space :)

Comment: So true.  I even tried it out a few times without realizing that I wasn't hitting the keys that I thought I was hitting, how embarrassing.

Answer (score 5):

Windows 7 has the [Snap](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/features/snap.aspx) feature which can be done with keyboard or mouse.

Keyboard shortcuts:

Snap left: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Left arrow</kbd>

Snap right: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Right arrow</kbd>

Full screen: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Up arrow</kbd>